# Disable Vaadin CSRF

Tags: spring-boot, vaadin, csrf

I'm using Vaadin 24.2 + Springboot 3.1.5 and Spring Security

So, according to this: [Vaadin Docs](https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/security/advanced-topics/vulnerabilities)

> All requests between the client and the server are included with a user-session-specific CSRF token. All communication between them is handled by Vaadin, so you don’t have to include and verify CSRF tokens, manually.

Now, I need to disable CSRF protection (for specific organizational needs). How can I achieve this?

Comment: Disabling security features is a bad idea. To rule out an X-Y-problem, what is this "organizational need"?

Comment: @cfrick My organisation requires Security Audit to be done with and without csrf protection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As documented [here](https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/configuration/properties), there's a `disable-xsrf-protection` configuration option that you can set to true to disable the built-in protection.

Comment: Astrand Thanks for the reply. But this is for Vaadin 8. Will it work in Vaadin 24? If so, what configuration should i do. It is not explained clearly.

Comment: Sorry for the outdated link. The same configuration parameter is present in Vaadin 24 as well. I updated my answer with an updated link. The same page also describes how to apply the configuration. If you're using Spring Boot, then note that there's also a separate page about how the same properties can also be set through `application.properties`.

Comment: Astrand. Thank you so much.